# On roots of irreducible quadratics modulo composites

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory, cryptography

Assume factorization of $N$ is unknown. What is the best complexity we know to find roots of the irreducible equation $$ax^2+bx+c\equiv0\bmod N?$$

Is this problem equivalent to any hardness results?

Comment: It's a bad idea to change the question after it was answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ability to find all roots leads to finding factorization of $N$. For example, if $N=pq$ is a product of two odd primes, and we find a root $x'$ of $x^2-1\equiv 0\pmod N$ such that $x'\equiv 1\pmod p$ and $x'\equiv -1\pmod q$, then we can compute $p$ as $\gcd(N,x'-1)$.

Comment: @MaxAleseyev What if $|a|$ or $|b|$ or $|c|$ is large?

Comment: Same idea works for $(x+u)^2-v^2$ where $u,v$ are large integers.

Comment: That is correct. Thank you. Is there an example if only $|a|$ is large?

Comment: E.g., consider $a^2x^2-1$.

Comment: I think the argument would not apply if the polynomial is irreducible and $|a|$ is large.

Comment: @Turbo: It's easy to construct polynomial $(a^2\bmod N)x^2-1$ that will be irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Ok. I did not reject your answer and I kept it as it is.